# Win+Spacebar no longer selects input methods in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard-layout

I have multiple keyboard layouts installed for the US English language. In the past, I was able to hit Win+Space to switch between them, but for some reason that is no longer possible. I have no idea what has caused this so stop working, I didn't change anything from a week or so ago when it was working fine.

Comment: My guess you have enabled a layout where that particular shortcut is some other key combination.

Comment: How would the layout change though? It has worked with these exact two layouts in the past.

Comment: You didn't give enough details to explain the behavior.  The keyboard layout would determine what each shortcuts did.  If you want more specifics post more details.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this complete list of Windows 8 global shortcuts](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=2ee8d462a8f365a0&id=2EE8D462A8F365A0!141), <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd> **should** still switch keyboard layouts.

This would indicate that some application you've installed has stolen the shortcut. It appears to be very hard to find out what application has taken a global shortcut but there are a couple of tools that claim to do it at least in part. Note that I've not tried these myself and I don't know if they work under Windows 8:

- [Hotkey Commander](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/)
- [ActiveHotKeys](http://www.tranglos.com/activehotkeys/)

Let us know if they work.

Comment: Hmm. Hotkey Commander has a sketchy website and only claims to support through Windows 7. ActiveHotKeys explicitly says it won't work with 64-bit machines (such as mine). I will let you know how it goes. EDIT - Hotkey Commander says that Win+Space is registered to explorer.exe, like many other hotkeys that *DO* work. So I don't think an application has stolen it.

Comment: I can confirm on my own W8 that adding a kb layout allows me to switch with Win-Space as expected with a nasty looking graphic on the RHS (which is where my taskbar is).